# Homework problem about the smallest sigma algebra:

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, proof-verification

Let $\mathscr{E} \subset 2^X $, then there is a unique smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing $\mathscr{E} $.

#### Proof(Attempt):

Since $\mathscr{E} \subset 2^X $, $2^X$ is $\sigma$-algebra containing $\mathscr{E} $. Let $\{ \mathscr{F}_{\alpha} \}_{\alpha \in A} $ be a collection of $\sigma-$algebras with $\mathscr{E} \subseteq \mathscr{F}_{\alpha} $ for all $\alpha \in A $. We have that

$$ \mathscr{M} = \bigcap_{\alpha \in A} \mathscr{F}_{\alpha} $$

is a $\sigma$-algebra and that $\mathscr{E} \subseteq \mathscr{M} $. Suppose there is a smaller $\sigma$-algebra $\mathscr{G} $ with $\mathscr{E} \subseteq \mathscr{G} $. It is evident that $\mathscr{G} \in \mathscr{F}_{\alpha} $ and so we must have $\mathscr{M} \subseteq \mathscr{G}$ showing that $\mathscr{M} $ is the smallest one. Suppose now there is another $\sigma$-algebra $\mathscr{U}$ with the same characteristics as $\mathscr{M}$. Since $\mathscr{M}$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing $\mathscr{E}$, then $\mathscr{U} \subseteq \mathscr{M}$. Similarly, $\mathscr{M} \subseteq \mathscr{M} $ and so we have established uniqueness.

Any feedback is much appreciated.

Comment: Replace "a collection of $\sigma$-algebras" by "the collection of all $\sigma$ sub-algebras of $2^X$ that $\dots$.'

Comment: What Andre said. The reason is when you say "a collection of gizmos" that means any collection at all, not necessarily including all gizmos. Otoh "the collection of gizmos" refers to the collection of _all_ gizmos. Say $S=\{1,2\}$. Then $S$ is a set of natural numbers, but $S$ is not the set of natural numbers.